# Print multicolor strings into richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

What is the **fastest** way possible to print multicolor strings into richtextbox if you want for example to print incoming serial data? I am using winforms.

I just put all strings which need to be printed in a queue and use a separate thread for printing the strings in the richtextbox.

**DataRecieved event:**

```
private void Port_dataRecieved(string a)
{
    prints.Enqueue("i" + a);
}
```

**btnSend_Click event:**

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialControl.Connected && tbInput.Text != "")
    {
        serialControl.Write(tbInput.Text + lineEnd);

        prints.Enqueue("c" + tbInput.Text + lineEnd);

        tbInput.Text = "";
    }
}
```

**Printer thread:**

```
private void PrinterThread()
{
    while (runPrinter)
    {
        if (prints.Count != 0)
        {
            string _out = prints.Dequeue();
            string toPrint = _out.Substring(1);

            if (_out[0] == 'c')
               printToConsole(toPrint, msgColor, msgPrefix, msgPrefColor, true, true);
            else
               printToConsole(toPrint, inTxtColor, inPrefix, inPrefColor, false, false);
        }
        else
            Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

**Printing:**

```
void printToConsole(string print, Color txtColor, string part, Color partColor, bool isMsg, bool endNL)
{
    while (print.Contains('\r'))
        print = print.Replace("\r", "");
    if (print.Contains('\n'))
    {
        string[] strings = print.Split('\n').ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            PrintString(strings[i], txtColor, part, partColor, isMsg, endNL);
        }
    }
    else
        PrintString(print, txtColor, part, partColor, isMsg, endNL);

    prevWasMsg = isMsg;
}

private void PrintString(string print, Color txtColor, string part, Color partColor, bool isMsg, bool nl)
{
    if (newString)
    {
        newString = false;
        printTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
    }
    else if (!prevStrHadNL && isMsg != prevWasMsg)
    {
        printNLTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
    }
    else if (prevStrHadNL)
    {
        printNLTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
    }

    if (nl)
        print += "\n";
    AppendText(print, txtColor);
}

private void printNLTimeAndPart(string part, Color partColor)
{
    AppendText("\n");
    printTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
}

private void printTimeAndPart(string part, Color partColor)
{
    if (timestamp == 1)
        AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), timeColor);
    AppendText(part, partColor);
}

delegate void AppendTxtCol(string txt, Color clr);
delegate void AppendTxt(string txt);


private void AppendText(string txt, Color clr)
{
    if (serialControl.ReadAllowed)
    {
        if (rtArea.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AppendTxtCol del = new AppendTxtCol(AppendText);
            rtArea.Invoke(del, txt, clr);
            /*MethodInvoker mi = delegate ()
            { rtArea.AppendText(txt, clr); };
            Invoke(mi);*/
        }
        else
            rtArea.AppendText(txt, clr);
    }
}

private void AppendText(string txt)
{
    if (serialControl.ReadAllowed)
    {
        if (rtArea.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AppendTxt del = new AppendTxt(AppendText);
            rtArea.Invoke(del, txt);
            /* MethodInvoker mi = delegate ()
            { rtArea.AppendText(txt); };
            Invoke(mi);*/
        }
        else
            rtArea.AppendText(txt);
    }
}
```

**AppendText method** from my richtextbox class:

```
public void AppendText(string text, Color color)
{
    this.SelectionStart = this.TextLength;
    this.SelectionLength = 0;

    this.SelectionFont = font;
    this.SelectionColor = color;
    this.AppendText(text);
    this.SelectionColor = this.ForeColor;
}
```

Comment: Use the SelectionColor property.

Comment: @LarsTech I need to print incoming serial data as fast as possible, but for accessing the ui thread i use method invokes and a 15char string prints for about 5ms, which is too much. The serial messages come every 1ms.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a DataReceived event for your serial port?   Your `while (runPrinter)` loop looks problematic, which includes a sleep call.  What makes you think the RichTextBox control is the problem here?

Comment: @LarsTech I am using my own serial class with a modified dataReceived event. The program is working almost as it should. The printing is too slow. It takes about 25ms, but there is a serial input every 1ms. The printing thread can't manage to print all the queue elements in time. The queue fills with over 3000 elements in about 30sec. I am really stuck. Please help!